# find entries but remind permission denied

Tags: permissions, find

I attempt to find any entries containing "thunderbird" to delete them

```
me@algorithms:~$ sudo find / -iregex ".*thunderbird.*" | grep Permission
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
```

but find do not have the permission to access ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’.

I am noticed I have the unlimited privilege to manipulate under the administrator mode.

How could I do things freely without any reminder of `permission denied"

Comment: `/run/user/1000` is not a persistent directory on your hard drive. It is a temporary file system (tmpfs) and will be deleted when you shut down your computer. You are not supposed to remove any files in it.

Comment: could you please transmit the comment to answer. @danzel

Answer (score 0):

`/run/` is a "tmpfs" mount. It is a temporary file system location (tmpfs), and the contents will not persist after a reboot.

You can see this for yourself and confirm it is the case. From terminal, type the command `mount`. The output will show you the different storage devices and mount types with information about their mount points and underlying filesystem type.

```
# mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1989412k,nr_inodes=497353,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=404008k,mode=755)
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

In the example above the first five mounts listed - `sysfs`, `proc`, `udev`, `devpts`, and `tmpfs` are specialized mounts that are not actually associated with a physical storage disk, but exist in non-persistent memory (ram) to facilitate the operating system and programs needs.

The sixth one listed, `/dev/sda2` is an actual physical disk mount, mounted to the root mount point `/` with the filesystem type `EXT4`. This is a persistent mount and the contents will generally survive reboot as they are backed on non-volatile storage.